# Having trouble moving a existing Model file into Require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I have moved the project into require now I am attempting to re-write some the code using backbone and underscore.  The traditional model, view , controller files exist.  Below Is the start of an  attempt to move the Model into a require define.

```
define ("Model", function () {

   var Model = function (connectToServer, soundTypeNum, isMobile)
   {
       //code
   };
return Model;

   // };//Error

  });//Fixed
```

But I am getting the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

EDIT: Now I am Getting Model is undefined when controller tries to create a new instance of Model:

```
var model = new Model(connectToServer);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that read `define ("Model", function (Model) {...});`?

Comment: Thanks Nit but that hasn't worked. The Existing Controller can no longer find Model once it is in the require define.  I probably need to move the controller in to a define too.  But why won't it find the Model!?

Comment: yep,you should plus you have to set `Model` in controller deps to be sure it will be loaded and available for controller

Comment: So the controller is trying to do this:
     var model = new Model(connectToServer);
Previously working with a shim.  But breaks now that model has been added into a require define.

Comment: Wait, are you declaring the Model in this file?  Or are you defining it as a dependency, then using it in this file?

Comment: I am trying to declare it. It's in existing Model file with Many Model.prototype.functions which I am trying to modularise with requirejs before using backbone and underscore to make code more manageable.

Answer (score 2):

I believe require.js must take an *array* of dependencies, even if there's only one.  Also make sure you're passing the dependencies to the function, as Nit said.

```
define(["Model"], function(theModel) {
    var Model = // initialize Model here
    return Model;
});
```

If you're not initiating Model somewhere else, then why is it a dependency?  You can pass a blank array of dependencies to require's function, if need be:

```
define([], function() {
    var Model = // initialize Model here
    return Model;
});
```

I'm not sure how you're planning on bringing backbone into play later "to make code more manageable".  I would think it would be easier to declare Model as a backbone model in this file where you initiate it.  Just define backbone as a dependency and extend its Model class.

```
define(["underscore", "backbone"], function(_, Backbone) {
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // initialize Model here.
    });
    return Model;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is very useful:)  Thank you.

My Model File declares Model but then extends it with prototype objects.  They are in the same file.  How would you handle them?